# Swift - Set vs Array

Tags: swift

On one hand I want an ordered collection, on the other hand I want every item in the collection to appear only once.

I can either use an array and sort it every time I insert an item - and insert only if not in the array.
or use a Set data structure and sort it every time i query the data

Does someone have better solution?

Comment: note that "ordered" and "sorted" are not the same. One specifies that the elements *have* an order, the other specifies *in what order*.

Comment: since you cannot make a set ordered/sorted but *can* make an array only contain unique values, go for the array and write some custom logic.

Comment: I build a chat service, and I want to add new message every time received from the server to the messages collection, i want the messages to be ordered by date. no problem. but when i have, let's say 60000 messages in one chat, and i receive 2000 more in one hour, the phone has to sort the messages very quick and show them on a table view, when the user scrolls, the table view refreshes and then it queries the data from the collection

Comment: luk2302, The problem is with the complexity

Comment: Have you considered `NSOrderedSet`? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSOrderedSet_Class/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several third-party libraries implementing an ordered set in Swift, so you could check them out.

Also, you could write your own implementation of an ordered set (you can base it on an existing one) if it is not an overkill for your task. The way you choose really depends on your app.

And in the end, you could use one of two ways that you proposed: using a built-in array or a set. In order to choose between them, take a look at your app: what action will be performed more often? Getting an access to elements in order (use array then) or addition/deletion of existing elements (probably, the set is the way to go).

**This part was edited based on comments below**

If you go for an array, note, that a built-in `contains` for arrays will not know that an array is sorted, so it will probably be O(N), not O(log(N)). So you should either write a custom replacement for the `contains` method, or (this is, once again probably a better way), write a custom collection class that implements `contains` the right way (however, since `contains` is a protocol extension method of `SequenceType`, my knowledge of Swift, I'm afraid, is not good enough yet to tell you how to do it properly, maybe someone else will).

**UPDATE (based on your comment to your question)**:

I believe, in your particular case (a chat app) array is superior. You only have to sort old messages once, and you will not probably try to add very old messages once again, you only have to make sure you don't add new messages twice (it is implementation-dependent though, so you know better, I'm just assuming). So you only have to check that the last messages in your old array do not overlap with first messages in the array that you add. Sort of :)

Comment: why??? then you will have to order both the set and the array, and inserting to an sorted array is in the same complexity of checking if an item is in the array...

Comment: @DanielMeltzer, yes, sorry, I missed that checking if an element is present in a **sorted** array is O(log(N)). Indeed, the "combined" solution is useless, you would just have to write a custom "contains" method for an array, that knows that the array is sorted and works at O(log(N)), and it would give you even better efficiency than the "combined" solution. I will update the answer. Also, I've already updated the answer based on your comment.